# Sublime Text 3 indenting of R comment object

Tags: r, sublimetext3

I am experiencing what I find to be annoying indentation behavior of lengthy R comment objects in Sublime Text 3. Given that Stack Overflow is likely not to mimic the behavior of Sublime Text 3 I am attaching a screen shot showing the behavior.

[image]

What I would like is for all the text to line up with the opening comment(" and the closing "), which is what you see with the second comment object, but not with the others. I have set the following rule in my user settings:

```
"indent_subsequent_lines": false,
```

The indentation shown above is with this rule in place.

Comment: Hard to tell whats wrong. Can't reproduce this. Maybe its a messup if different packages or smth...

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate this in ST build 3131 by typing `comment("` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `")` - the opening paren causes the subsequent lines to be indented and the closing paren doesn't unindent it again.

This is because the R package that ships with ST doesn't contain any indentation rules, so it uses the default ones. The default rules have `indentParens` set to true, which causes this behavior.

The fix is to create a [`tmPreferences` file](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/metadata.html#metadata-files) to override this behavior for R:

Save the following as `Packages/User/R indentation.tmPreferences`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.r</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>indentParens</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Keith, I should have mentioned that I am using Windows (7 and 10 on two different machines). I would guess the Apple Computer reference does not apply in that case?

Comment: ST uses Apple's Property List files because it aimed to be compatible with TextMate, which originally defined the `tmPreference` format - and TextMate is only built for Apple's MacOS. So it is correct, that this format is being used by ST, even on Windows.

Comment: Keith, I created the file--copying and pasting your code. I still get the annoying indentation behavior. Is there any magic I need to do to activate the code?

Comment: you shouldn't need to - it works for me. Did you save in your `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` folder? with the exact name `R indentation.tmPreferences`?

Comment: When I copied and pasted your code into ST3 and saved it to the indicated file name ST3 added the extension .xml to the file name. However, I just now removed the .xml extension. Closed the program, reopened it. Closed the sample file, reopened it. And I still get the annoying indentation.